# in php with the fopen code

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a php page with `fopen()` this php file will house the passwords and usernames for my clients database info like host adress and stuff like that, but when I try stuff like this:

```
$filename = "pass.php";
$ourfile = fopen($filename, '<?php session_start(); ?>') or die(mysql_error());
fclose($ourfile);
```

It just rejects it and says:

> Warning: fopen(pass.php) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No
>   error in C:\wamp\www\forum\installer\checkinstall.php on line 12

I want to have something like:

```
<?php
session_start();
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "hey";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
?>
```

but ever time it just wips out that error.

Comment: `fopen($filename, '<?php session_start(); ?>')` --- where have you seen such syntax?

Comment: well i just thought it would work as you can use 'w' for example

Comment: `'<?php session_start(); ?>'` - what this line means?

Comment: it means start session. like you see in 3 block of code thats what im tring to achieve

Comment: in your context it means nothing!

Comment: @user891362: nope, it doesn't. It is just weird string that means nothing - it is just a string

Comment: The "w" isn't writing "w" to the file.... it's opening the file for __W__ riting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fopen() **opens** a file, you need to use fwrite() to actually **write** to the file. Please look at the examples in the documentation on www.php.net

```
$filename = "pass.php";  
$ourfile = fopen($filename, 'w');  
fwrite($ourfile, '<?php session_start(); ?>');  
fclose($ourfile);
```

And the filesystem doesn't give mysql errors.

Comment: oh thanks i was lead on the wrong road. thanks for setting it straight

Answer (score 0):

The second for `fopen` is invalid:

`The mode parameter specifies the type of access you require to the stream.`

You could use `w` if you want to write into that file.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

P.S.: The `'<?php session_start(); ?>'` will not get you the contents of the session if that is what you were trying to do.

Comment: I think OP is trying to write the string '<?php session_start(); ?>' to their file

Answer (score 0):

WTF?

`fopen` for php file? And than? `eval`???

`fopen() or die(mysql_error())`???

Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php

Answer (score 0):

you fopen call is wrong.

The fopen php syntax is:

```
fopen($filename, options)
```

Where options are:

- w - Writable
- r - Readable
- w+ - Writable in append mode
- r+ - Readable in append mode.

But that was well Documented on php.net site!!

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example function using file_put_contents wrapper & heredoc, hope it helps.

```
<?php 
function clientConfig($clientOrPath, $host="localhost",$db,$user,$pass){

    $config = <<<EOT
<?php
session_start();
\$dbhost = "$host";
\$dbname = "$db";
\$dbuser = "$user";
\$dbpass = "$pass";
?>
EOT;

    if(!file_exists($clientOrPath.'/config.php')){
        file_put_contents($clientOrPath.'/config.php',$config,LOCK_EX);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


if(clientConfig('client1', 'database', 'root', 'pass')==true){
    //success
}else{
    //fail
}
?>
```